# different background image on each page of mobile site?

Tags: css, image, mobile, background-image

Currently, I'm using this bit of code to call a still image background instead of the video played on the regular site:

```
media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
         html{
           background: url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed !important;
           background-size: cover;
           height: 100%;
         }
}
```

I'd like to utilize a different image for each page, how do I go about achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you supply a different ID for the body tag of each page, you can then target each one with a different image:

HTML:

```
<body id="homepage">

<body id="about">
```

etc...

Then, within your media query, the CSS would be:

```
body#homepage {
    background-image: url('img/homepageBackground.jpg');
}

body#about {
    background-image: url('img/aboutBackground.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that this is a Wordpress site change this? The `<body>` tag is in the header, which is universal across all pages.

Comment: I don't see why this would limit you... I found this article http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-background-by-page-id which uses Wordpress' `body_class()` method to give the `body` tag an identifier